# Reverse printing of input numbers after zero is received

Tags: python

In this code, I want the user to enter an integer, and until zero is entered, I receive input from the user. After receiving the number zero, I print the entered numbers except zero in the reverse order of their insertion.

I have two problems:
-One is how to not print the number zero in the output of the program
-And the second is how to correctly add the entry before the while loop to the num list

```
inp = int(input())
num = []
num.append(inp)
while inp > 0:
    out = int(input())
    num.append(out)
    if out == 0:
        for i in num[::-1]:
            print(i)
```

> ```
> Sample input :   
> 3  
> 4  
> 7  
> 4  
> 9  
> 0
> ```

> ```
> Sample output :  
> 9  
> 4  
> 7  
> 4  
> 3
> ```

> ```
> But my output is like this :  
> 0  
> 9  
> 4  
> 7  
> 4  
> 3
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the break and while statement you can use a infinite loop and break it only when `inp` is zero otherwise keep adding the `inp` to the list.

And in the end print the numbers in the reverse order as you're already doing.

This is more simple because:

- You read `if inp == 0: break` you automatically see that the while stops looping (rather of being forced to read a nested for inside a `if`).
- You split your code in to: collect numbers and print numbers (while and for statements).
- You no longer need to repeat your `int(input(...))` call (before while and when whiling since everything is done inside the loop).

```py
num = []

while True:
    inp = int(input())
    if inp == 0:
        break
    num.append(inp)

for i in num[::-1]:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the condition that checks if the input is `0` before appending the value to the list

```py
inp = int(input())
num = []
num.append(inp)
while inp > 0:
    out = int(input())
    if out == 0:
        for i in num[::-1]:
            print(i)

    num.append(out)
```

---

### But

even the first input can be `0`, so modify your code to this

```py
num = []
out = 1

while out > 0:
    out = int(input())

    if out == 0:
        for i in num[::-1]:
            print(i)
    else:
        num.append(out)
```